# Is there an ``arrayAdd`` method or something to facilitate array additions?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, addition

So I have an array

```
static final int N = maxNofActiveThreads;
static final int[]arr = new int[N*nofEntries];
```

Where the `N` threads write to mutually exclusive regions of the array.

I should now like to add a monitoring thread that will periodically collect the results for decision-making by simply summing up all the threads' tables.

I.e. in pseudo-code

```
int[] snapshot = arr[0 : nofEntries] + arr[nofEntries : 2*nofEntries] + ... + arr[(N-1) * nofEntries : N*nofEntries]
```

The obvious choice would be to simply create

```
int[] snapshot = new int[nofEntries]
System.arrayCopy(arr,0,snapshot,0,nofEntries);
```

and then walking through the rest of `arr`, adding one value at a time.

Is there a smarter/more efficient way?

Oh, and we don't care if we miss an update every so often, it will eventually show up on the next pass and that's fine. No need for any synchronisation.

(I should also mention that the project I'm working on requires me to use Java 7.)

Comment: Why do all the threads share one array? The "no need for any synchronization" statement is a bit worrying too.

Comment: @Kayaman well, if it turns out I *do* need to run through the array, I at least have spatial locality. Also, it gives both the modifying and the monitoring threads an easy access to all threads' data, especially useful as thread IDs are being passed around rather than the threads being kept the same. And there's enough memory barriers in the rest of the code that updates will eventually be made visible even without additional synchronisations.

Comment: You can always write such a method yourself.

Comment: @Sweeper I can, yes. But my question was whether there already IS something. No point in re-inventing the wheel, is there?

Comment: Not in the standard JDK. Arrays have never been that important. Other libraries exist, but they're yours to find, as recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can imagine is to use the `Arrays` class static method `parallelSetAll`. As it tries to parallelize operation it may be more efficient. Javadoc for another parallel method says:

> ... computation is usually more efficient than sequential loops for large arrays.

So you could use:

```
private int tsum(int index) {
    int val = 0;
    for (int t=0; t<N; t++) {
        val += arr[index + t * nofEntries];
    }
    return val;
}
```

and:

```
    IntUnaryOperator generator = (x) -> tsum(x) ;
    int[] snapshot = new int[nofEntries];
    Arrays.parallelSetAll(snapshot, generator);
```

Comment: Thank you, but that not only requires Java 8, it's also much more expensive. Your access pattern is all over the place and that you're able to compute the entries in parallel does not gain you enough performance to justify losing spatial locality. (I don't know why you thought Javadocs for "*another* parallel method" would be relevant.)I actually tried this: (naive: https://ideone.com/T2UaZf ), (parallel: https://ideone.com/hSuAYK ) parallel either ran out of time or out of memory.

Comment: @User1291: the efficiency of parralel operation may greatly depend on the system notably hardware...

Comment: I don't deny that. But I very much doubt you can get an increased performance in a memory-bound problem like this by introducing more random accesses.